# It is possible to export a catch error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i´m doing a webapp using react, it is a journalApp with a backend in firebase, im trying to make a display message on the login screen when the email is not registered in firebase, my question is if there is a way to use the catch error when the mail is not registered.[Here is the message that i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVAGr.png) [This is the code that generates the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GWM.png)

Thanks to all!

Comment: You could dispatch the error and handle it like you would any other action.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't use screenshots to show text and code.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes of course!
you are able to run any code in the `catch` block. Try the following:

```
export const startLOginEmailPassword = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(({user}) => dispatch( login(user.uid, user.displayName)))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        alert(e.message);
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice!, i didnt thinked in that way, it is an improvement, if i want it to dispatch that to my login screen to make an html div with the message i could use destructuring ?, +1 for the answer!

Comment: yes you can destructure the returned object to access the values you want to then dispatch them :)